# Most frequent vowel in string python 3

Tags: python, string, if-statement, for-loop

I have created the program for the most frequent vowel in a string but the problem that i am having is i want to print only one letter for the most frequent vowel, not both. My code is displayed below:

```
from collections import Counter
words = input("Enter a line of text: ")
vowel = "aeiouAEIOU"
x = Counter(c for c in words.upper() if c in vowel)

most = {k: x[k] for k in x if x[k] == max(x.values())}

for i in most:
    vowel = i
    y = most[i]
    print("The most occuring vowel is:",vowel, "with",y,"occurences")

if vowel != words:
    print("No vowels found in user input")
```

When i run the code for example i enter "aa ee" it will print:

```
The most occuring vowel is: A with 2 occurences
The most occuring vowel is: E with 2 occurrences
```

I only want it to print either A or E?

Comment: "Either A or E" - well, which one? You told the interpreter to create a dictionary and then loop through that. How is it supposed to know which one you want? Why even tell it to do all that if you only want one?

Comment: How do you want to choose which vowel to show? Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 3):

Why you don't simply use [`Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) which is most appropriate way for doing this job?

```
words = input("Enter a line of text: ")
vowels = set("aeiouAEIOU")
x = Counter(c for c in words if c in vowels)

print x.most_common()
```

Also note that you don't need to use `word.upper` since you have all the vowels type.And as said in comment you can use `set` for preserving the vowels which its membership checking complexity is O(1).

Comment: other tweaks: `vowel` should be `vowels`, `vowels` should be a `set`, and that `set` should look like `{'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'}` (since you're doing `words.upper()` it doesn't need to include the lowercases). I know you're just copying this, but...

Comment: @AdamSmith Yep, thank, but I think there is no need to use `set` for short iterables

Comment: But it's checking it once per character in `words`. Converting to `set` for one lookup is different than converting to `set` for N lookups

Comment: No need? Is there any 'need' to use a sequence? Is it costing you something to use a `set`? What if `words` is very big and you're going to be checking many characters? `set`'s are always the right choice for membership testing.

Comment: @AdamSmith Oh you man for `words`, but that will make the answer wrong since OP wants to find the frequency of vowels!

Comment: No, @AdamSmith meant for vowels.

Comment: @Kasramvd `[c for c in "some long string goes here" if c in some_string]` is much slower than `[c for c in "some long string goes here if c in some_set]` since each character is going through the membership test. It's true that `vowels = 'AEIOU'` is much faster than `vowels = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'}`, but if you're testing against it more than a few times then you're still going faster.

Comment: Nice answer. Just a nitpick: he *does* need to use `.upper()`, otherwise `A` and `a` would be considered different vowels.